# Tools to deploy webpart pages between farms?

Tags: web-part-pages

I'm looking for some thoughts on how to deploy connected webpart pages between farms (SDLC).
I'm looking to do this without WSP packages so that we're "cloud ready".

I think DocAve's Content Manager module can do it. I know ShareGate can't. Does anyone know of other tools?

I'm using the PnP Template powershell commands to deploy the rest of the site collection. What's not coming over are configured pages with query string filters and list web parts that are connected.

Thanks.
-Doug